# Apache Commons HttpClient with user authentication

Tags: apache, scala

Need to do an HTTP GET with user ID and password authentication using the Apache Commons HttpClient:

```
val targetHost = new HttpHost("url", 8080, "http");
val credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));

val authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());

val context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
context.setAuthCache(authCache);

val client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
var response = client.execute(new HttpGet("url"), context);
var statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

But it's not able to fetch the data from the URL as it is failing to connect to the URL. Can someone assist?

Comment: The question should include specific error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters to `HTTPHost`.  I'm pretty sure that you don't intend to connect to a server named `url`.

Comment: HttpHost protocol was not supported with http, worked with https

Comment: Its Working now